# Node.js http-proxy traffic monitoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to set up a proxy server that should return the `http requests` from any page that I'm accessing.

Basically, if I navigate to `www.google.com` then I'm expecting to get the following requests:

[image]

Is this achievable using `node-http-proxy` module?

I've tried the following code, but can't figure out how to get the requests..

```
var http = require('http'),  
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create a proxy server with custom application logic
//
httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {  
  //
  // Put your custom server logic here
  //

  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000
  });
}).listen(8000);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {  
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied: ' + req.url +'\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

UPDATE:
I configured your browser to use my proxy server, and changed the code as follows:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create a proxy server with custom application logic
//
var proxy = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {  
  //
  // Put your custom server logic here
  //
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000
  });
})

proxy.listen(8000);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log(proxyReq.url);
});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied: ' + req.url +'\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

But there are no logs in the console when I'm accessing different websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to configure your browser to use your proxy server:

For chrome,

1. go to settings,
2. search for "proxy",
3. click "change proxy settings",
4. click LAN settings,
5. and then add information about your proxy server.

I am not sure if you need to restart the browser, but your request should be sent to the proxy after that.

Here is a an example of what I got working for myself:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Http Proxy Server with bad target
//
var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  target:'http://localhost:9005' 
});

proxy.listen(8005);

var http = require('http');
//
// Create your target server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    target: 'http://'+req.headers.host
  };
  console.log(req.url)
  console.log(req.headers.host)
  req.host = req.headers.host;
  proxy.web(req, res, options, function(err){console.log('err', err)}); // errorCallback is optional
}).listen(9005);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res) {
  console.log('request url', JSON.stringify(req.url, true, 2));
});
```

It works only for http for now.

Comment: This works, but how can I get the HTTP request urls? If I do `console.log(req.url)` then it logs:
`http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt
http://google.com/
http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt
http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt
http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt  
and so on`

Comment: I'm expecting to get:
`http://google.com/`, `?gws_rd=cr&ei=ed4SWeCbNIKYsAHxmIvACw`, `googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png` etc.

Comment: I think you need to see the [documentation on request rewriting](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#setup-a-stand-alone-proxy-server-with-proxy-request-header-re-writing). here you should have access to the original request

Comment: For this one I should set the `HTTP Proxy` = 127.0.0.1 and `Port` = 5050 ? If I do this I'm getting `The proxy server is refusing connections` when trying to access a website...

Comment: You're right, but I was referring to the code from here https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#setup-a-stand-alone-proxy-server-with-proxy-request-header-re-writing

Comment: In the last line of their code they are opening the server that listens on that port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143866/discussion-between-valip-and-vladimir-m).